# Chain Rule of Calculus as a Group Property?

Tags: calculus, group-theory

I read that [the chain rule and inverse function theorem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7J2iA.png) are expressions of the group property of successive non-singular transformations.

**How do you say this more formally?**

My guess is that we are saying something like 'the action of a derivation on the algebra of differentiable functions is invariant under the action of the group of non-singular transformations on the algebra'? *How would you clean this up and perhaps illustrate with an example?*

The quoted passage mentions the implicit function theorem too, I don't see this as *directly* relating to a group of coordinate transformations (even though it is equivalent to the inverse function theorem), perhaps it's talking about another group property?

**Are other theorems from calculus like the mean value theorem or Lagrange multipliers talking about group properties?**

For example, [Young's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_of_second_derivatives#In_Lie_theory) seems to be about about the action of one-parameter groups on a function being commutative, though I don't know how to phrase this in a nicer way either.

Also the definition of a convexity seems like it comes from the action of an affine group on a function v.s. it's coordinates, i.e. it's commutator is positive or negative?

Any help? :D

Answer (score 2):

The statements in the book are not quite precise or correct.

In the first statement, by "non-Euclidean spaces" the author means differential manifolds that are not open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$, not  non-Euclidean geometry of curved Riemannian manifolds.

The chain rule is that the differential of a composite function is the composition of the differentials.  This is not a *group* property as the author claims, since the differentials do not have to be invertible for the chain rule to hold.

In the second statement, the inverse function theorem is not a group property.  The function may be from one manifold to another, so there is a group**oid** not a group (for the invertible functions).  And the existence statement in the theorem is not a formal consquence of any group structure, it is more like solving a differential equation to go from a linear inverse of the function's differential, to a full compositional inverse of the function in a neighborhood of a nonsingular point.

Comment: How do you answer it in the case where it does hold, i.e. non-singular transformations on a function acting on the same space?

Comment: I'd make a category of open sets and differential functions mapping them to each other.  Then taking differential is a functor, and there is a isomorphism/equivalence/local-isomorphism (didn't sort out which it is exactly) between the subcategory (groupoid) of invertible functions and the functions with invertible differential.  That's the chain rule and inverse function theorem.